# Остановка работающего потока по клику на кнопку

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть кнопка, которая генерирует событие `ButtonClick`, и метод должен проверять, запущен ли поток и его убивать, а потом создавать заново. Код ButtonClick сейчас:

```
MyThread1 = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate () { SmallFinder("Аргумент1", "Аргумент2", "Аргумент3"); });
if (MyThread1.IsAlive == true)
{
    MyThread1.Abort();
    MyThread1.Join();
}
MyThread1.Start();
```

И за пределами метода:

```
private static Thread MyThread1;
```

В метод нужно передавать 3 аргумента, для этого и используется делегат. Однако данный код не работает, что не так и как это исправить?

---

P.S. Мне кажется, что это не работает, что каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку MyThread1 присваивается новое значение.

Comment: Вы пишете: "P.S. Мне кажется, что это не работает, что каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку MyThread1 присваивается новое значение.". И Вы определённо правы :) Надо "перетасовать" строки кода: сначала поставьте ветку `if (MyThread.IsAlive == true)`, а затем присвоение нового значения переменной `MyThread1` и стартование этого нового потока :) Ну разве что ещё условие улучшить надо: `if ((MyThread != null) && (MyThread.IsAlive)) ...`

Comment: @velial, вы правы, оформите как ответ, что бы я поставил его, как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пишете: "P.S. Мне кажется, что это не работает, что каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку MyThread1 присваивается новое значение.".

И Вы определённо правы :) Надо "перетасовать" строки кода: сначала поставьте ветку `if (MyThread.IsAlive == true)`, используя объект уже существующего потока, а потом уже создавайте и запускайте новый.

Т.е., код будет примерно следующий (рекомендую ещё сделать проверку на `null`):

```
// освободить уже существующий поток, если он есть
if ( (MyThread1 != null) && (MyThread1.IsAlive) )
{
    MyThread1.Abort();
    MyThread1.Join();
}

// создать новый поток (ссылка на старый/завершённый освобождается)
MyThread1 = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate () { SmallFinder("Аргумент1", "Аргумент2", "Аргумент3"); });
// запустить новый поток
MyThread1.Start();
```